# VirtualBox does not capture mouse/keyboard

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, mouse

I have used VirtualBox and Ubuntu for years.  I'm pretty familiar with both.  So, I am used to what it means to capture the mouse/keyboard.  I do not have to do this very often though.

Recently (weeks/months?) it seems capturing has stopped working.  I'm not sure what is at fault.

I am on Ubuntu 15.04.  I run Gnome 3.  I am running Virtual Box 4.3.26_Ubuntu r98988.  I downloaded one of the Microsoft Windows vm's (Windows 8, IE 11) from http://modern.IE.  I have installed the guest additions into the OS.

When I try to capture the mouse/keyboard using the right control key, I get the pop-up from VirtualBox warning me it's about to capture the mouse and keyboard, with the buttons on the dialog to either 'Cancel' or 'Capture'.  I press the 'Capture' button.  The icon in the bottom right highlights indicating they have been captured.  However, they are not.  I can move the mouse out of the virtual box window.  Additionally if I press the 'windows' key on the keyboard when the Windows-virtualbox is the focus, it is Ubuntu/Gnome that registers the keypress.

I am trying to determine what I need to fix, so that capturing the mouse/keyboard in VirtualBox works correctly.

Comment: Did you find the problem in the end?

Comment: Not directly.  But the last time (only within the last month) I had to do a new virtual machine I decided to remove all virtual box packages from my machine and reinstall.  I've done this before, and it hasn't helped, but this last time it did.  I now have it working fine.  I can not explain what might have changed.